# Draw line from a point to another line (along x-axis or y-axis) in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I would like to make use of the intersection tools to draw a line to another line in a way that it only reaches along the x-axis or y-axis. I mean I currently *think* that I would achieve this via the intersection part... but I'm not entirely sure on that. I hope the attached picture clears it up properly. Is this possible?

*Note*: The coordinate values are only that simple for the sake of demonstration.
*edit:* Edited with better code and screenshot to clarify the problem, a thank you to Jake.

[image: Image with target points whose values only change on one axis]

**MWE**

```
    \documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
tikz
}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
    %
    \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6.2,6.2);
    %
    \draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[anchor=west]{x};
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{y};
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x};
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y};
    %
    \begin{scope}[color=black]
    \filldraw (1,1) circle (0.08cm) node (A) {} node[anchor=north,fill=white,yshift=-0.1cm] {A};
    \filldraw (6,6) circle (0.08cm) node (B) {} node[anchor=west,fill=white,xshift=5pt] {B};
    \filldraw (4,2) circle (0.08cm) node (C) {} node[anchor=south,fill=white,yshift=0.1cm] {C};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[very thick] (A) -- (B);
    \draw[->,>=latex,very thick,dashed] (C.center) -- ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
    \draw (2,5) node[fill=white] {\textcolor{red}{from C\ldots}};
    \draw[color=red,very thick] (2,2) circle (0.1cm) node[above,yshift=5pt,fill=white]{to this point};
    \draw[color=red,very thick] (4,4) circle (0.1cm) node[below,yshift=-5pt,fill=white]{or this one};
    %\node (Ex) at (....)?
    %\draw[->,>=latex',very thick,dashed] (E.center) -- ($(A)!(E.135)!(B)$);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I understand that right, you want to draw a horizontal or vertical line starting from `(C)` and ending at the diagonal line?

Comment: @Jake Yes, exactly, you understood right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After loading the `intersections` library, you name the involved paths using `name path=<name>`, then you can use the `name intersections={<options>}` key to find intersection points (details in Section **13.3.2 Intersections of Arbitrary Paths** of the pgf manual).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
    %
    \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6.2,6.2);
    %
    \draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[anchor=west]{x};
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{y};
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x};
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y};
    %
    \begin{scope}[color=black]
    \filldraw (1,1) circle (0.08cm) node (A) {} node[anchor=north,fill=white,yshift=-0.1cm] {A};
    \filldraw (6,6) circle (0.08cm) node (B) {} node[anchor=west,fill=white,xshift=5pt] {B};
    \filldraw (4,2) circle (0.08cm) node (C) {} node[anchor=south,fill=white,yshift=0.1cm] {C};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[name path=diagonal,very thick] (A) -- (B);
    \draw[->,>=latex,very thick,dashed] (C.center) -- ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
    \draw (2,5) node[fill=white] {\textcolor{red}{from C\ldots}};
    \draw[color=red,very thick] (2,2) circle (0.1cm) node[above,yshift=5pt,fill=white]{to this point};
    \draw[color=red,very thick] (4,4) circle (0.1cm) node[below,yshift=-5pt,fill=white]{or this one};

  \path[name path=line1] (C) -- +(-3,0);
  \path[name path=line2] (C) -- +(0,3);
  \draw[thick,blue,name intersections={of=diagonal and line1,by={Int1}}] (C) -- (Int1);
  \draw[thick,green,name intersections={of=diagonal and line2,by={Int2}}] (C) -- (Int2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, now I see how I could have used that. Thank you for showing me. This is the code I am going to use.

Comment: Dear Gonzalo, thanks for the codes. But `\addplot` does not work properly. I am used to employ `\begin[axis]...\end[axis]` for `\addplot`.

Answer (score 9):

These points are best found via an intersection. I used the `intersection of` syntax (which is a wrapper for the `intersection cs`). The `|-`/`-|` short hands are used to find a coordinate in the `perpendicular cs`.

I took the liberty to clean up a little bit in the code and use styles. Also the labels `A`, `B`, and so on are in fact `label`s.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
  dot/.style={shape=circle,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=+1.6mm,label={#1}},
  dot/.default=,
  dot*/.style={dot={#1},fill=black},
  dot*/.default=,
  doto/.style={dot={#1},draw=red,solid,thick},
  doto/.default=,
  shorten/.style={shorten >={#1},shorten <={#1}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
    \draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (6.2,6.2);

    \draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right]{x};
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[left] {y};

    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6} {
      \draw [thick](\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt) node[midway,below] {\x};
      \draw [thick](-2pt,\x) -- (2pt,\x) node[midway,left]  {\x};
    }

    \node[dot*=below:A] (A) at (1,1) {};
    \node[dot*=right:B] (B) at (6,6) {};
    \node[dot*=right:C] (C) at (4,2) {};

    \draw[very thick,shorten=+3pt] (A) -- (B);

    \node[doto=left:C(A)] (C'A) at (intersection of C--A|-C and A--B) {};
    \node[doto=left:C(B)] (C'B) at (intersection of C--B-|C and A--B) {};

    \path[-latex',very thick, dashed] (C) edge (C'A) edge (C'B);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hm... just for the record: this worked, but can't mark more posts than one as a a solution (still a bit new to TeX.sx). So thank you. But your advanced reply actually is of some sort disadvantage to me as I do not follow your definitions of all those dot styles (-> if I were to use this code, I couldn't edit it properly to produce the right output :(). Thank you for cleaning up my code as well.

Comment: @henry Well, that doesn’t change anything. Even with your code the coordinates `(intersection of C--A|-C and A--B)` and `(intersection of C--B-|C and A--B)` still result in the same coordinates on the line from A to B. What you do with these coordinates I leave to you. (This works only with straight lines, otherwise use the `intersections` library.)

Comment: @henry If you’re willing to show what your intended output is, I’ll give some ideas on how to use it (better?). I find it very confusing that you draw a circle, then place an empty (and rectangular!) node at the some place (that is later referenced) and than manually (`xshift`/`yshift`) place another node to label that dot. The same can achieved with *one* node with an `outer sep` (or `shorten` paths as in my example) and a `label`. I think this is clearer then your code but you have by no means to use this code. `:)` The bigger the MWE, the more I’ll invest in what results in what.

Comment: 1st:Why did the damn auto-completion of your name not work. 2nd:In my first comment I meant to say that I accepted Gonzalo's code as a solution as I find it quite easier to understand. 3rd:My code is that way just for the sake of display. 4th: As for shifting nodes as labes of other nodes, this is necessary for finetuning imho. I rather do it this way, otherwise I'd do it with the `\foreach`-command (provided by you guys). But thanks for offering help :)

Comment: @henry 1st: Because you and me are the only users commenting here and I am the author of this answer, so I get notified anyway. 2nd, 3rd and 4th: No hard feelings, I’m sure somebody will find my answer helpful. I only hope that you do not make yourself more work than needed.

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks. It just focuses on the part in question. As the function is linear, no need to use intersection technique.

### Remarks:

- the left figure is created by specifying the points `L` and `R` first. Then `C` is constructed from `L` and `R`.
- the right figure is created by specifying the point `C` first.

```
\documentclass[crop,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}
\psset{algebraic,saveNodeCoors}

\def\f{x+.5}
\def\g{y-.5}% inverse of \f

\begin{document}

% C is defined last
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,0)(4,4)
    \pstGeonode[PointName={none,none,default},PointSymbol={none,none,default}]
        (*.5 {\f}){L}
        (*2 {\f}){R}
        (R|L){C}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](L)(C)(R)
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{3}{\f}
\end{pspicture}

\hspace{12pt}

% C is defined first
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,0)(4,4)
    \pstGeonode(2,1){C}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed]
        (**{\g} N-C.y)
        (C)
        (*N-C.x {\f})
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{3}{\f}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing this code, it is useful for users of PSTricks.